# Angular set ui-select default from another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I'm working on creating an edit page for a simple task entry.

One of the fields is using ui-select to generate a dropdown of 'projects' that the task can be assigned to.

The issue I am having is that the form is wrapped in ng-controller="getTask as vm"
However the ui-select field is wrapped in ng-controller="Projects as vm" to generate the list.

Im trying to set the default value of the project field from the getTask controller, however I cant do so as its out of the scope.

Whats the best way of making $select.selected alterable from the getTask controller?

Here's the code I am dealing with:

```
<form ng-controller="getTask as vm">
<input type="text" name="task_name" value="{{ vm.task.name }}" />    

<div ng-controller='Project as vm' class="form-group select">
    <ui-select ng-model="selectedItem">
       <ui-select-match>
           <span ng-model="vm.formData.prject_id" ng-change="vm.setProject($select.selected.id)" ng-bind="$select.selected.project_name"></span>
           <input  type="hidden" name="project_id" value="{{ $select.selected.id }}">
       </ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="project in (vm.projects | filter: $select.search) track by project.id">
          <span ng-bind="project.project_name"></span>
      </ui-select-choices>
   </ui-select>
</div>
</form>
```

Hope that makes sense. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at $rootScope. It is the scope defined through all your application, defining your object 'selected' in it is the easiest way to achieve this.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

Note that someone would blame the excessive use of rootScoped objects in large application, because it can get messy.